# Android Studio: Error (26,13) Gradle Project sync failed

Tags: java, android, gradle

[image: Error Message]
Every time I create a new android studio project this error pops up and the project becomes useless.
This is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dean.youtubeplayer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: Can you post the full error from Android Studio? A Gradle sync failure is normally accompanied by a few suggestions.

Comment: Why don't you click on `install repo and sync`?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the "Gradle Script" and click on the "build.gradle" (the first one with the project and not the module app. Replace the all projects line with this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```